# FailedCreatePodSandBox event in EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

In an EKS Kubernetes cluster, I have a cronjob that creates pods in every 5 minutes. The cronjob always works well but it sometimes shows `FailedCreatePodSandBox` event that I cannot understand its reason. Even though this event happens, cronjob works without any problem. Event logs are as follows,

```
39m         Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   Pod          Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "synthetic-test-cronjob-1565344380-bg97c": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\"": unknown
34m         Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   Pod          Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "synthetic-test-cronjob-1565344680-xq9rl": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\"": unknown
24m         Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   Pod          Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "synthetic-test-cronjob-1565345280-v5pz9": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"\"": unknown
9m39s       Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   Pod          Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "synthetic-test-cronjob-1565346180-xxpmc": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:301: running exec setns process for init caused \"signal: killed\"": unknown
```

As you can see, two different line numbers appear in the error message. `process_linux.go:402` and `process_linux.go:301`

What are the possible reasons for this warning and how can I prevent it or should I just ignore it since it doesn't affect the cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some **known issues** related to the error messages provided in your example. Take a look at the following **github issues**:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68190

https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/1914

> We believe that this error may also occur when exceeding any container
>   cgroup limit 
>   (e.g. memory, cpu, pids).